# how can i get dynalically create the same id for two different html code blocks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

you can view it here:

http://www.daftblogger.com/managing-the-new-growth-challenge-for-frontier-market-investing-amlctf-regulations/

scroll down to the bottom of the post and view the second author box

example i have this:

```
<a href="#tab1">bio</a>
<a href="#tab2"></a>
```

then in the body

```
<div id="tab1"></div> 
<div id="tab2"></div>
```

I want to dynamically add the id both in the href and also in a div because more divs and hrefs will be added dynamically

http://pastebin.com/RKRwDpyx

Comment: ID's always need to be unique..

Comment: Please indent your code, or post a JSFiddle.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use PHP to dynamically create two dfifferent HTML code blocks with the same id?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Rather than ask us how to do what you think will do what you want, just ask about what you're trying to accomplish. For a better explanation, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @ phillip thats exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: This is wrong. You can't have two identical IDs, it will break any Javascript that tries to access the element. What is your end goal with this?